# xaml: scrollbar in web browser

Tags: xaml, scrollbar

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,84,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="browser" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" IsScriptEnabled="True" />
    </Grid>
```

This is what I coded to initialize web browser in my app. But while displaying content it doesn't have a scroll bar. i need to have in web browser, hence user can realize where they are.

Here's a screenshot pic : http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/7811/44o.png

Best answer will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use webbrowser control in following way:

```
<phone:WebBrowser Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"  x:Name="browser"    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" IsScriptEnabled="True" />
```

I don't see much use of the grid as shown in Code snippet, kindly remove it.

Hope this help you....